# Libgdx font issue

Tags: java, text, libgdx

I am trying to draw text on my buttons for a start menu.

I can draw the buttons and everything except the font/text just fine.

Here is the font code:

Initializing:

```
    buttonFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal(
                                "StartMenu/gamefont.fnt"), false);

    buttonFont.setScale(0.2f);
```

Here is where i draw the stage, the stage has the font within it:

```
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);

    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);

    sb.begin();

    stage.draw();

    sb.end();
```

This is the stuff for initializing some more stuff:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    if(stage == null)
        stage = new Stage();

        stage.clear();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        style.font = buttonFont;

        style.up = skin.getDrawable("Button");

        style.down = skin.getDrawable("Button");

        startGameBtn = new TextButton("Start Game", style);

        startGameBtn.setWidth(250);

        startGameBtn.setHeight(150);

        startGameBtn.setX(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - startGameBtn.getWidth() / 2);

        startGameBtn.setY((float) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 1.5));

        startGameBtn.addListener(new InputListener() 
        {


            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                game.setScreen(new Gameplay(game));
            }


        });

        stage.addActor(startGameBtn);

        stage.addActor(lb);

    }
```

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Is there are reason why you don't use `TextButton`?

Comment: I am using textbuttons

Comment: Oh sorry, did not see that... Which Libgdx version are you using? It seems like they have changed something regarding BitmapFont in the latest version...

Comment: Any update on your problem ?
Did you try my solution ? Does that work ? If no, what do you observe ?

Comment: I still haven't fixed it, no. I believe that there might be something wrong with the font file. What's your solution? I did not see it.

Comment: Look at the answer below. I wrote it 48 h ago.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and tell ya how it's going.

Answer (score 0):

I find weird that you create your button in the `resize()`.

What I would suggest, and what works for me, is initialize everything in the `create()`, draw the stage in the `render()` and put the Listener in the `show()`

Initialization

```
create(){
    //Define the stage where you'll draw the TextButton
    stage = new Stage();
    //Define your font
    buttonFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("StartMenu/gamefont.fnt"), false);
   //Define the skin that contains your images
   textureAtlas = game.assets.get("Images.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
   skin.addRegions(textureAtlas);

   //Define the TextButtonStyle
   textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
   textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("Button");
   textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("Button");
   textButtonStyle.font =  buttonFont;
   textButtonStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
   textButtonStyle.downFontColor = new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);

   //Define the TextButton
   startGameBtn = new TextButton("Start Game", textButtonStyle);
   startGameBtn.setWidth(250);
   startGameBtn.setHeight(150);
   startGameBtn.setX(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - startGameBtn.getWidth() / 2);
   startGameBtn.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 1.5f);   

   //Add the TextButton to the stage
   stage.addActor(startGameBtn);
}
```

Drawing of the TextButton

```
render(){
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

Using the TextButton

```
show(){
    startGameBtn.addListener(new InputListener(){
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
        {
            game.setScreen(new Gameplay(game));
        }
    });
}
```